# Reshape the dataframe using PySpark/Pandas according to custom logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I have a dataframe with structure similar as shown below:

|  | INP_A | INP_B | OUTP_A | OUTP_B | LVL_NUM | BTCH_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | m1 | b1 |  |  | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | m12 | b12 | m1 | b1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | m13 | b13 | m1 | b1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | m21 | b21 | m12 | b12 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | x1 | b1 |  |  | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | x12 | b12 | x1 | b1 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | x13 | b13 | x12 | b12 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | x21 | b21 | x13 | b13 | 3 | 2 |

The desired outcome is basically, the reshaped (long-to-wide) dataframes that I need to write into parquet files for each unique BTCH_NUM value saved with the name format including the BTCH_NUM value.

The desired structure of DataFrames for each BTCH_NUM (which need to be written in separate files) is as follows:

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

For BTCH_NUM = 1:

|  | INP_A.1 | INP_B.1 | OUTP_A.1 | OUTP_B.1 | INP_A.2 | INP_B.2 | OUTP_A.2 | OUTP_B.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | m12 | b12 | m1 | b1 | m21 | b21 | m12 | b12 |
| 1 | m13 | b13 | m1 | b1 |  |  |  |  |

For BTCH_NUM = 2:

|  | INP_A.1 | INP_B.1 | OUTP_A.1 | OUTP_B.1 | INP_A.2 | INP_B.2 | OUTP_A.2 | OUTP_B.2 | INP_A.3 | INP_B.3 | OUTP_A.3 | OUTP_B.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x12 | b12 | x1 | b1 | x13 | b13 | x12 | b12 | x21 | b21 | x13 | b13 |

Now, the logic behind this reshaping is that, for each unique LVL_NUM value I am converting the old columns into new columns with the LVL_NUM as suffix. (for eg: INP_A becomes INP_A.1 for LVL_NUM = 1 and so on).

*Some info about the data*: Here the data is populated such that for each LVL_NUM (in each unique BTCH_NUM) the OUTP_A and OUTP_B values of higher LVL_NUM are INP_A and INP_B values of lower LVL_NUM respectively. For eg: (m1, b1  are OUTP_A, OUTP_B values in LVL_NUM = 1 and INP_A, INP_B values in LVL_NUM = 0)

**What I have tried so far?** (after reading tons of pandas/pyspark documentations and stackoverflow answers)

```
# I am using pandas but I'll prefer a pyspark implementation otherwise I can do with pandas for now
import pandas as pd 

# Dummy data (Actually, I am using parquet files containing dataframes)
data = {
    'INP_A': ['m1','m12', 'm13','m21','x1','x12', 'x13','x21'],
    'INP_B': ['b1', 'b12', 'b13', 'b21','b1', 'b12', 'b13', 'b21'],
    'OUTP_A': ['', 'm1', 'm1', 'm12','', 'x1', 'x12', 'x13'],
    'OUTP_B': ['', 'b1', 'b1', 'b12','', 'b1', 'b12', 'b13'],
    'LVL_NUM': [0,1,1,2,0,1,2,3],
    'BTCH_NUM': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
}

# Convert to a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#  Group the df into multiple dataframess w.r.t. the BTCH_NUM
grouped_dfs = [i[1] for i in df.groupby("BTCH_NUM")]

# Iterate over each df, transform into long-to-wide format and print the result
# To do: Instead of printing, save the df in a new file
for i in grouped_dfs: 
    i = i.drop(columns='BTCH_NUM')
    i = i[i['LVL_NUM']>0]
    df_out = i.set_index('LVL_NUM')
    df_out = df_out.stack()
    df_out.index = df_out.index.map('{0[1]}.{0[0]}'.format)
    df_out = df_out.to_frame().T
    s = df_out.columns.to_series()
    df_out.columns = [df_out.columns, s.groupby(s).cumcount()]
    df_out = df_out.stack().sort_index(level=1).fillna('').reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index().drop(columns='index')
    print(df_out)
    print(' ')
```

If you'll run the above code in jupyter, you'll get the following output:

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

|  | INP_A.1 | INP_A.2 | INP_B.1 | INP_B.2 | OUTP_A.1 | OUTP_A.2 | OUTP_B.1 | OUTP_B.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | m12 | m21 | b12 | b21 | m1 | m12 | b1 | b12 |
| 1 | m13 |  | b13 |  | m1 |  | b1 |  |

|  | INP_A.1 | INP_A.2 | INP_A.3 | INP_B.1 | INP_B.2 | INP_B.3 | OUTP_A.1 | OUTP_A.2 | OUTP_A.3 | OUTP_B.1 | OUTP_B.2 | OUTP_B.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | x12 | x13 | x21 | b12 | b13 | b21 | x1 | x12 | x13 | b1 | b12 | b13 |

If you'll compare the actual output with the required output, you'll notice, the only difference is that the columns are in different order. So, that is the first thing I need help with (columns are currently coming in sorted order but I need the "required output" format only) and yes, if there are any better approaches to do the whole reshaping process I am open for that too. Thank you so much for your time if you read this far.

> PS: I am very new to pyspark/pandas/python/Asking-Questions-on-StackOverflow. So, this question may not be perfectly written. Please ask if you have any confusion regarding the reshaping part or any part in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `pivot` after reworking the DataFrame:

```
df2 = (df
 .assign(idx=df.groupby(['BTCH_NUM', 'LVL_NUM']).cumcount(),
         LVL_NUM=lambda d: d.groupby(['BTCH_NUM', 'idx']).cumcount().add(1)
        )
 .pivot(index=['BTCH_NUM', 'idx'], columns='LVL_NUM')
 .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
 .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}'), axis=1))
)
```

output:

```
             INP_A_1 INP_B_1 OUTP_A_1 OUTP_B_1 INP_A_2 INP_B_2 OUTP_A_2 OUTP_B_2 INP_A_3 INP_B_3 OUTP_A_3 OUTP_B_3 INP_A_4 INP_B_4 OUTP_A_4 OUTP_B_4
BTCH_NUM idx                                                                                                                                        
1        0        m1      b1                       m12     b12       m1       b1     m21     b21      m12      b12     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
         1       m13     b13       m1       b1     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
2        0        x1      b1                       x12     b12       x1       b1     x13     b13      x12      b12     x21     b21      x13      b13
```

Then you get the individual sub-DataFrames by slicing, for example for BTCH_NUM 1:

```
df2.loc[1]
```

Comment: @Chris correct, I missed this part (although values seem to be there in the provided output?), then a simple initial `.query('LVL_NUM > 0')` should be added ;)